# If statement evaluates to true with with no value

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary comprehension that I want to run and for some reason the if statement although it is false, the result is the first choice instead of the else block statement.

```
        groups_dict = {
            choice_dict.get("group_name"): []
            if choice_dict.get("group_name", False)
            else (choice_dict.get("display_name"), choice_dict.get("value"))
            for choice_dict in choices.get("tags")
        }
```

Odly enough, the same logic works fine if it's a list.

```
 groups_list = [
        (choice_dict.get("group_name"), [])
        if choice_dict.get("group_name", False)
        else (choice_dict.get("display_name"), choice_dict.get("value"))
        for choice_dict in choices.get("tags")
    ]
```

In both cases I have a list of dictionaries that I want to process. Each dictionary has the same structure of `{"display_name":X , "value": Y, }` and some of the dicitonaries have an added `{"group_name": Z}` in them. My intention is to convert the list of dictionaries into a hierarchy of lists based on the "group_name" key if it is present and otherwise have the `("display_name", "value")`

For some reason in the first example, the if statement although is evaluated to False due to the item not having a "group_name" key, still executes the statement that is for the if true and I have no clue why.

Edit:
An example of what chocies.get("tags") would be:

```
choices = {"tags":[
    {'display_name': 'Tags not assigned', 'value': 'none'},
    {'display_name': 'Chair', 'value': '2', 'group_name': 'kitchen'},
    {'display_name': 'Sofa', 'value': '3', 'group_name': 'living_room'},
    {'display_name': 'TV', 'value': '4', 'group_name': 'living_room'} 
]}
```

From this I want to have the following restructuring:

```
(
    'living_room': (("tv", 4), ("sofa", 3)),
    'kitchen': (("chair", 1)),
    ('Tags not assigned', none) 
)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, can you share an example of what `choices` looks like?

Comment: Also, note that in the first example, the dictionary uses `choice_dict.get("group_name")` as a key, so if `choice_dict` doesn't have the key `"group_name"`, it will be `None`, and will be overwritten for each `choice_dict` that doesn't have that key

Comment: @FlorentMonin Added an example

Comment: can you also show the choice_dict data

Comment: If there are multiple dictionaries with no `"group_name"`, what do you want the output to look like?, Also, it is unclear where the "0" from `('Tags not assigned', 0)` comes from, since the value for that dictionary is `'none'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible to do what you want in a dictionary comprehension, because you have to refer to previously defined *key: value* pairs in order to upgrade *value* with new data.

Also, a default key for data without *group_name* is needed, maybe `None` or `"none"` or an empty string etc.

So the code may look like this:

```
# input data
choices = {"tags":[
    {'display_name': 'Tags not assigned', 'value': 'none'},
    {'display_name': 'Chair', 'value': '2', 'group_name': 'kitchen'},
    {'display_name': 'Sofa', 'value': '3', 'group_name': 'living_room'},
    {'display_name': 'TV', 'value': '4', 'group_name': 'living_room'} 
]}

groups = {}    # output data
no_group = 'NO GROUP'   # default group name
for ch in choices['tags']:
    pair = (ch['display_name'], ch['value'])
    # set a new empty list as a default value for a new key
    groups.setdefault(ch.get('group_name', no_group), []).append(pair)
```

Comment: Yea turned out I needed to do a set from all the "group_name" values and modify that empty set from there.